# Data Binding single string

Tags: sapui5

I have a button into a bar in my XML view:

```
<Button xmlns="sap.m" id="idMenuBarSoc" text="{flagSocietyBar}" visible="true" icon="sap-icon://filter" press="handlePressSocFilter"/>
```

in the controller I write (in the init method):

```
this.getView().setModel('Oracle-Society', 'flagSocietyBar');
```

but if i test my application the button not show any text...   ('')

What should I write in `text="{?????????}"`  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not going to work... You haven't defined the model type (I think you want to use JSONModel?) and you haven't set the data to the model.

By the look of your code, I *think* you wanted to define a property 'flagSocietyBar' with value 'Oracle-Society', am I correct?
However, the `setModel(oModel, sName)` method is used incorrectly here. [According to the API](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject.html#setModel), oModel cannot be of type string but should be of type sap.ui.model.Model.

Modify your code to the following:

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
oModel.setData({flagSocietyBar : "Oracle-Society"});
this.getView().setModel(oModel);
```

and your button should then bind to `text="{/flagSocietyBar}"`

If you need named models, specify it as such:

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
oModel.setData({flagSocietyBar : "Oracle-Society"});
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel, "myModel");
```

and your button should then bind to `text="{myModel>/flagSocietyBar}"`

Comment: Ok, it work! And if I want set the model not of a specific view and define a name of a model? How I cal recall it in the XML view?

`var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();`
`oModel.setData({flagSocietyBar : "Oracle-Society"});`

`sap.ui.getCore.setModel(oModel,'MyModelName')`

Comment: I try to search in the documentation... some like '>/...'

Comment: BTW, if the answer is correct, could you please mark it as such? That way others could benefit from it as well. Thanks in advance :)